# What is the maximum stoage size of lokijs.js?

Tags: lokijs

Have you tried lokijs.js with large amount data for desktop browsers and What is the maximum stoage size of lokijs.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On node.js the virtual limit is the amount of RAM utilizable by your process (because Loki works in memory so it can't store more data than it fits in memory). So on a normal dev machine that would be something in the region between 1gb and 3-4gb. In a browser, it's 5MB.

Comment: Thanks @joe, Loki fits for my requirement except storage size.